# How to map mouse left click to left shift key in AutoHotKey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I need to map mouse left click to left <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and mouse right click to left <kbd>ALT</kbd> key for better productivity :P.

But I DO NOT want to block any of key combinations like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> etc.

So far, I'm able to get <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality with (`LAlt & *::Suspend, On`).
But can't make it work for shift key.

Issue's I need to resolve:

1) not able to type in uppercase with <kbd>shift</kbd>+`any_key`
2) key combinations not working like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+`any_key` or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+`any_key`

Here's my script so far:

```
LAlt & *::Suspend, On
LShift::LButton
LAlt::RButton
```

Holding LEFT <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key simulates the left click hold which is great and would like to keep it this way.

Answer (score 0):

See [modifier symbols](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) about the tilde prefix (`~`) in particular.

```
~LShift::LButton
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, Already tried this before and it gives the weird behavior because it is not blocking shift action.... on click of shift it also selecting the text like shift + click

Comment: Isn't that basically what you're telling it to do? You're using it as both a shift button and an `LButton` at the same time.

Comment: there's a subtle difference.. holding shift and moving cursor should behave like mouse left click but holding shift and entering any key like z should return Z. I know it is possible to achieve but i'm new to AHK scripting

Comment: 1. Sounds like a quite complex script involving monitoring changes in the mouse pointer coordinates, then. You might want to look into [MouseGetPos](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm). 2. You're saying you *know* it's possible, but I'm not sure how you could implement it without annoying side effects or making the script and key inputs quite unresponsive and slow to the point of being practically unusable. Do you have any working piece of code in other languages?

Comment: If not, write some pseudocode and then I might be able to help you with that. (dang, this 5-minute restriction on editing comments sucks.)

Comment: hey i found a script which is giving me the expected behaviour ~Lshift::  
Send {LButton Down} ; Press the LButton key Down
KeyWait, LShift ; Wait for the LShift key to be lifted
Send {LButton Up} ; Release the LButton key
return; end; only problem now is how to behave ctrl + LShift as Ctrl + LButton.i.e.. ctrl+lbutton opens link in new tab in chrome ?

Comment: 3. `{LButton Down}` still interferes with your ordinary key inputs. 4. As I said already, I see no way of doing it without significant interference/conflicts. You're trying to map just too much to a single key.

Comment: yes and i guess i can live with this. keeping this script in mind.. is it possible to achieve LCtrl & LShift::Lctrl+LButton ? Strangely it is not working somehow.